# Audio record output's mime type is set as video

Tags: android, audio, media-player, record

I wrote a simple audio recorder program. I set the output format as THREE_GP, but the resulting file's mime type is set as video (when I try to view the file details).

Any idea why?

```
 mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
 mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
 mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
 mRecorder.setOutputFile(recordingFilePath);
```

Comment: to my knowledge 3gpp is used when recording videos, not sure. try using AMR

Comment: @jeffreyveon Do you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Sirlate No, I think I found some work around, but can't remember what it was. Maybe I stopped using 3gpp.